# Can not access ANY directories in phonegap through the getDirectory() function

Tags: file, cordova

This should be quite simple but I just cannot get it to work

**Szenario:**
I want to iterate through my folders with the phonegap file API

**Problem:**
I can not get the getDirectory() function wo work

**Very simple example:** (to illustrate my problem)

```
var fileSystem, basePath;

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, doStuff, function(error) { 
    notificationservice.log('Failed to get local filesystem: ' + error.code); 
});

function doStuff(fs) {
    fileSystem = fs;
    basePath = fileSystem.root.fullPath;

    var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry('', basePath);
    readDirectory(directoryEntry);
}

function readDirectory(directoryEntry) {
    var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < entries.length ; i++) {
            notificationservice.log(entries[i].fullPath);

            fileSystem.root.getDirectory(entries[i].fullPath, {create: false}, function(dir) {
                    notificationservice.log('SUCCESS');
                }, function (error) { 
                    notificationservice.log('Failed to get directory'); 
                });

        }
    }); 
}
```

I can access my folder with the `new DirectoryEntry()` but whenever I try the access a directory with the `getDirectory()` function I fail - if anyone could help me correct the above code so that the `fileSystem.root.getDirectory()` would not return an error I´d be very thanksfull !

Please note:
I use the eclipse editor for deployment and deploy to a nexus 7
(if possible the code should work an plattforms like iOS or win as well)

thanks,
matthias

by the way: I am sure there are a lot of questions which actually solve this issue - however, I haven´t been able to find ANYTHING working for me...

Answer (score 0):

according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Silly me - was hooked on script which I got from the web - I have to use the .name property (relative path from the current directory) like this

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory(name, {create: false}, function(dir) {...
```

- THIS QUESTION IS SOLVED (and sorry if anyone wasted time on this)